# Effectively query the number of friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm current first getting all friends of a certain user and then take the size of the array as the number of friends. My concern is, since every time I'm retrieving all friends information from the database, it is potentially (or obviously) inefficient. So I'm wondering if there's a way that could query the number of friends of a certain user effectively without getting any other information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your relations are declared correctly, you should be able to do `user.friends.count` in order to generate a DB-level count.

**See here in my console the SQL queries generated** (`Drug has_many :details` and `DrugDetail belongs_to :drug`):

```
irb(main):003:0> Drug.first.details
  Drug Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "drugs".* FROM "drugs" LIMIT 1
  DrugDetail Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "drug_details".* FROM "drug_details" WHERE "drug_details"."drug_id" = 1771
=> []

irb(main):004:0> Drug.first.details.count
  Drug Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "drugs".* FROM "drugs" LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "drug_details" WHERE "drug_details"."drug_id" = 1771
=> 0

irb(main):006:0> Drug.first.details.to_a.size
  Drug Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "drugs".* FROM "drugs" LIMIT 1
  DrugDetail Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "drug_details".* FROM "drug_details" WHERE "drug_details"."drug_id" = 1771
=> 0
```

**In your case**, if you have your relations like this:

```
User has_many :friends
Friend belongs_to :user
```

Then this should be executed at the DB-level and be faster than your first piece of code:

```
User.first.friends.count
```

Comment: In `User.first.friends.count`, how to I specify a particular user's friends count?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on what user you need. In the show action of the Users controller it would be `User.where(id: params[:id])`. How do you usually retrieve this particulaer user?